# laptop won't boot any OS no windows,no linux,no android x86 7 r5

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, android-x86

I have a dell vostro 1015 core 2 duo with 3GB of RAM and a Seagate HDD with 250GB capacity, when I turn it off and leave it for a long time, it boots up any OS and works normally, but takes a short time then it freezes completely,with the light off Hdd all flash,and after forced reboot from power key the proccess stopping during boot. Some days i was running live android x86 7 r5 from usb without hard drive because it was locked with user password, so i sent it to a professional man to unlock it and android was running smoothly from usb pen drive,but one day when i tried to boot this system without the hdd,it worked for a while 6 minutes then freezes completely and now happens with the unlocked seagate hard drive and i can't install any os,please any solutions

Answer (score 0):

> android was running smoothly from usb pen drive,but one day when i
> tried to boot this system without the hdd,it worked for a while 6
> minutes then freezes completely

Get the Dell diagnostics on a bootable USB key and see if you can get it started to run Dell diagnostics and see what is wrong.

If you cannot even start diagnostics, take the machine to a local repair shop and have it serviced.